# Remove a GSource(timeout) and adding the same GSource to the same context without recreating the source

Tags: glib

There are 2 threads. Thread 'A' is the manager and Thread 'B' is the worker.
I created a GmainContext in 'B'. Then I added a timeout source and attached it to the GMainContext in 'B'.

The Thread A starts. It works for a while and it wants to remove the timeout source from 'B'. After sometime it needs to add the same source, possibly with the same source id back to the same context in GMainContext in 'B'.

I think its possible, but I am unaware of implementation.

Here is what I tried.

```
static GMainLoop* _mainLoop;
static GMainLoop* _taskThreadLoop;

static gboolean _toTaskThread(void* /*data*/)
{
    printf("TaskThread\r\n");
    return true;
}

static gboolean _toMain(void* /*data*/)
{
    printf("Main Thread\r\n");
    return true;
}

void* taskThreadMain(void* /*data*/)
{
    GMainContext *context = g_main_context_new();
    g_main_context_push_thread_default(context);

    _taskThreadLoop = g_main_loop_new(context, FALSE);
    GSource* toSource = g_timeout_source_new(5000);

    g_source_set_callback(toSource, _toTaskThread, nullptr, nullptr);
    g_source_attach(toSource, context);

    // Run the loop on taskThread
    g_main_loop_run(_taskThreadLoop);

    // Destroy all the resources used in this thread
    g_source_destroy(toSource);
    g_main_loop_unref(_taskThreadLoop);
    g_main_context_unref(context);

    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    _mainLoop = g_main_loop_new(nullptr, true);
    g_timeout_add(2000, _toMain, nullptr);

    GThread* taskThread = g_thread_new("thread", taskThreadMain, nullptr);

    g_main_loop_run(_mainLoop);

    if (_mainLoop)
    {
        g_main_loop_unref(_mainLoop);
        g_main_loop_quit(_taskThreadLoop);
    }

    g_thread_join(taskThread);
    g_thread_unref(taskThread);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What should I do in the main()so that the source in taskThread is removed and how do I add it back.